# Number of functions from one set to another

Tags: combinatorics, functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

This is what I am given:

Suppose the set $A$ has $m$ elements and the set $B$ has $n$ elements. There are $2^{mn}$ relations from $A$ to $B$ and $n^m$ functions from $A$ to $B$.

And I want to know

> $(b)$ If $m = n$, find the number of functions from $A$ onto $B$.

Comment: Do you mean onto as in "injective"?

Comment: I meant Surjection

Answer (score 1):

Since we are dealing with finite sets,

the first element of $A$ has $n$ choices.

the second element of $A$ has $n-1$ choices as suppose two values are being mapped to the same value, the function cannot be surjective as we won't have any preimage.

Hence the $i$-th element has $n-i+1$ choices.

multiply these numbers up, we have $n!$ such functions.

Comment: Wouldn't it be m! Instead?

Comment: That works for injection but I am talking about surjection

Comment: for this question $m=n$.

Comment: Yes. So I was thinking something like m choose 1 like the binomial coefficient. Does this not work?

Comment: for your comment about injection and surjection, prove that if $m=n$, injections and surjections are equivalent.

Comment: Then doing m choose 1 does not work?

Comment: So can I just write something like n(n-1)(n-2)....(1)=n!=m!

Comment: it depends on what do you mean by $m$ choose $1$, of course I can write $n$ choose $1$ multipled by $n-1$ choose $1$ and so forth.

Comment: yes for your latest question.